# Отслеживание загрузки классов

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть приложение desktop на java. Хочу сделать картинку предзагрузки. На примере той же Intellij Idea. Понимаю что необходимо делать отдельный поток, который будет отображать окно загрузки, но вот каким образом понять что основное приложение загрузилось не могу. В самом приложении идёт загрузка классов и их данных.

Comment: На чем пишете приложение? Тоже в данный момент создаю приложение на JavaFX, в JavaFX можно имплементировать класс предзагручика javafx.application.Preloader

Comment: @zuvladimir на swing